# Turning columns result set into independant rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot, unpivot

I am pretty new to this and have been struggling over one issue.

I have a result set which for each Opportunity in a table (id as primary key), provides a date for a first cashflow (DFCFW) as a column and the 10 following columns (CFW1, CFW2, ...., CFW10) being the 10 possible cashflows for each of the 10 following years, expected as anniversary dates of the first cashflow.

I would like to create a view which displays, for all the opportunities, three columns:
opportunity.id, date of the cashflow, cashflow; there should be 10 records for each opportunity.

Any suggestion how to achieve this ?

Thank you so much

Fred

---

To add some clarity:

What I have today looks like this:

[image]

What I am looking for is the following (dates are in European format):
[image]

Comment: there is a broader context and way more columns describing opportunities

Comment: What you're looking for is what should be in the database, and with a pivot you could retrieve what you "have today".  If you don't change your DB structure, you'll waste a lot of time coding for nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, MySQL [doesn't have](http://ubiq.co/database-blog/unpivot-table-mysql/) an `UNPIVOT` operator which would be very handy in this case - you'll just have to roll up your sleeves and do it manually I'm afraid. See the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=91a95a06605b94e0851d10ae89d6bf9a) - I've only done 3 `CFW`s - you can just copy and paste for the remainder.

```
CREATE TABLE example
(
  opp_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  region VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
  first_cfw DATE NOT NULL,
  cfw1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  cfw2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  cfw3 INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO example VALUES
(1, 'Europe', '2020-06-01', 100, 100, 100),
(2, 'USA',    '2020-02-01', 200, 200, 200),
(3, 'Europe', '2017-10-01', 150, 150, 150);
```

And then run:

```
SELECT opp_id, region, first_cfw AS the_date, cfw1 AS cost_fw
FROM example
UNION ALL
SELECT opp_id, region, DATE_ADD(first_cfw, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), cfw2 
FROM example
UNION ALL
SELECT opp_id, region, DATE_ADD(first_cfw, INTERVAL 2 YEAR), cfw3
FROM example
ORDER BY opp_id, region, the_date ASC
```

Result:

```
opp_id  region  the_date    cost_fw
1       Europe  2020-06-01      100
1       Europe  2021-06-01      100
1       Europe  2022-06-01      100
2          USA  2020-02-01      200
2          USA  2021-02-01      200
2          USA  2022-02-01      200
3       Europe  2017-10-01      150
3       Europe  2018-10-01      150
3       Europe  2019-10-01      150
```

I would agree with those comments which suggest that you should consider redesigning your schema - your main schema should look like the final result. As a  rule of thumb, tables should be tall and skinny and not short and fat!

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked like a charm

Comment: @FredKTrashmail - if it worked for you, please feel free to mark the answer as correct :-) - also, it might help others looking for a similar solution into the future!

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in my comment, saving the data in that for,m results in problem

Also save the dates always in mysql date_form, or else you have to convert them al the time

This shows you gow it is done without dynamic sql, if you had 100 of these columns, you have to use the INFORMTION_SCHEMA, to get all column, but basically you di the same as in the example.

Of course you have to add tghe rst yourself, it is quite obviuous how tpo procedd to get all 10 columns

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `Opp_id` INT,
>   `REgion` VARCHAR(8),
>   `date1erCFW` VARCHAR(10),
>   `CFW1`INTEGER,
>   `CFW2` INTEGER,
>   `CFW3` INTEGER,
>   `CFW4` INTEGER,
>   `CFW5` INTEGER,
>   `CFW6` INTEGER,
>   `CFW7` INTEGER,
>   `CFWB` INTEGER,
>   `CFW9` INTEGER,
>   `CFW1O` INTEGER
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`Opp_id`, `Region`, `date1erCFW`, `CFW1`, `CFW2`, `CFW3`, `CFW4`, `CFW5`, `CFW6`, `CFW7`, `CFWB`, `CFW9`, `CFW1O`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Europe', '01/06/2020', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '0', '0', '0'),
>   ('2', 'USA', '01/02/2020', '200', '200', '200', '200', '200', '200', '200', '200', '200', '0'),
>   ('3', 'Europe', '01/10/2017', '150', '150', '150', '150', '150', '150', '150', '150', '150', '150');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `Opp_id`, `Region`, `date1erCFW`, `CFW1` FROM table1
> UNION 
> SELECT `Opp_id`, `Region`, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`date1erCFW`,'%d/%m/%Y') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR,'%d/%m/%Y'), `CFW2` FROM table1
> UNION 
> SELECT `Opp_id`, `Region`, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`date1erCFW`,'%d/%m/%Y') + INTERVAL 2 YEAR,'%d/%m/%Y'), `CFW3` FROM table1
> UNION
> SELECT `Opp_id`, `Region`, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`date1erCFW`,'%d/%m/%Y') + INTERVAL 3 YEAR,'%d/%m/%Y'), `CFW5` FROM table1
> UNION 
> SELECT `Opp_id`, `Region`, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`date1erCFW`,'%d/%m/%Y') + INTERVAL 4 YEAR,'%d/%m/%Y'), `CFW6` FROM table1
> ORDER BY `Opp_id`, STR_TO_DATE(`date1erCFW`,'%d/%m/%Y')
> ```
>
> ```
> Opp_id | Region | date1erCFW | CFW1
> -----: | :----- | :--------- | ---:
>      1 | Europe | 01/06/2020 |  100
>      1 | Europe | 01/06/2021 |  100
>      1 | Europe | 01/06/2022 |  100
>      1 | Europe | 01/06/2023 |  100
>      1 | Europe | 01/06/2024 |  100
>      2 | USA    | 01/02/2020 |  200
>      2 | USA    | 01/02/2021 |  200
>      2 | USA    | 01/02/2022 |  200
>      2 | USA    | 01/02/2023 |  200
>      2 | USA    | 01/02/2024 |  200
>      3 | Europe | 01/10/2017 |  150
>      3 | Europe | 01/10/2018 |  150
>      3 | Europe | 01/10/2019 |  150
>      3 | Europe | 01/10/2020 |  150
>      3 | Europe | 01/10/2021 |  150
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6bb8971e49da60fa99e59118b600d18e)*